# Android application UI Design Clarification

Tags: android-layout, user-interface, android

I recently started a designing a new android app similar on the lines of Google Offers. I am looking to design a user interface similar to Google Offers. I have tried looking at HorizontalScrollView and ViewFlipper. Both does not give me the effect of moving across view as seen in Google Offers. Anyone have any idea on what kind of design patter would have been used in Google Offers. I am leaning towards Horizontal Scroll View but I am not able to get the same effect, is there something I am missing. I would appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [`ViewPager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html).

Here are a few samples on implementing a `ViewPager` with tabs:

- http://blog.peterkuterna.net/2011/09/viewpager-meets-swipey-tabs.html
- http://thepseudocoder.wordpress.com/2011/10/13/android-tabs-viewpager-swipe-able-tabs-ftw/
- http://viewpagerindicator.com/ (Not a tutorial, a bit of an extension library)

I would also look into [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) (there is even a `ViewPager` tutorial in the `demos` folder of the download) and the [compatibility libraries](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html) for using `Fragment`s (part of the `ViewPager`) below Android 3.0.